# Windows Azure Service Bus Billing

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have a question about the azure service bus billing.
If I have the following code, and a message isn't sent for a long time say 5 hours.

Assume I only have one subscription and the code is as below.
In this scenario over that 5 hour period what do I get charged (is it once for sending and once for downloading, or do I incur charges for the polling keep alive that azure implements in the background)?

```
enter code here
   var subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnString, topic, subscriptionName);
            while (true)
            {

                var message = subscriptionClient.Receive();
                if (message != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        message.Complete();


                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // Indicate a problem, unlock message in subscription
                        message.Abandon();
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("null message received");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code above you will get charged for a single message every time the Receive call returns (even if the result is null). The default timeout for the Receive call is 60 seconds so in the case there is no message for 5 hours, your code will return every one minute and then sleep for 25 seconds so assume that per hour you will get charged for 48 messages (1 min timeout and 25 second wait). You can call the overload of [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh330856.aspx) that takes a timeout and pass in 5 hour timeout there. Here the connection will be kept alive for 5 hours before it returns and thus no charges will occur during that time.

From a back of the envelope calculation: A single receiver, running with one minute timeout with no wait and no real messages will get a message charged every minute. That is less than 5cents for the entire month. See billing calculator [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full)

Comment: I am using "subscriptionClient.Receive(TimeSpan.MaxValue);" and I am not sending any msgs to that subscription then the connection should be KeptAlive right. But after some time i am getting Null msg. I want to know how long the connection will be kept alive...

Comment: @Abhishek Lal, Would there be any disadvantage to keep alive for 5 hours (obviously with lots of subscribers we'd end up incurring at lot less of a charge if it only returned a null message once per 5 hours rather than once per minute).

Comment: No real disadvantage, just that you cannot cancel that call so in case you wanted to do a shutdown or close the request it would not return that control to you for that duration.

Answer (score 1):

Only Message Transaction will be counted( Send,Receive)... Azure not charging for KeepAlive Messages...

Refer MSDN topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_1

Comment: I can't see where it confirms in the link that they don't charge for keep alive?

Comment: @DermFrench Check out [What happened to the “Service Bus Connections” billing meter?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_6), they don't charge but you are limited to 2 million relay hours

Comment: @DermFrench see this msdn (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/53a766d7-47b8-48d8-b594-7ac7e2275bc5/)... I was asked the same question long before and got answer from ClemensV who is the PM of Service Bus in Microsoft...